# HTTP request to IP based URL fails in aws lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm in a lambda and want to make a POST request to an API without a domain name, for instance:

```
const url = "https://ii.iii.i.iii:8080/api"
```

This fails. It will timeout. However, locally it works.

My lambda have internet access - changing to

```
const url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos"
```

works fine.

Is because I'm in a VPC, so my client will try to call to the IP address in the VPC? What can I do allow calling APIs at external IP addresses like this?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you are using the correct IP address? Are you sure it is an IP address that is available on the public Internet?

Comment: Yes and yes, tested from code or postman locally it works fine

Comment: I assume you have a NAT Gateway in your VPC, which is allowing the Lambda function to access the Internet. Otherwise the Lambda function wouldn't be able to access anything on the Internet, regardless of domain name or IP address. The only reason an IP address would not work (when a domain name does) is if the IP address conflicts with the IP range of the VPC, but in that case it would be an internal IP address anyway, not a public IP address. It sounds like your external service may be blocking AWS IP addresses.

Comment: Which service performs HTTPS termination: CloudFront or API Gateway?  Do you store the TLS certificate in ACM?  Does certificate include `ii.iii.i.iii` as a domain?

Comment: @AlexChadyuk this is Lambda making an HTTP request, not an HTTP request being made to a Lambda function.

Comment: Yes, we have a NAT in VPC. Might be blcoked, Ill have to examine that. I did look into the route tables, there is one entry there saying: 0.0.0.0/0 igw-**** Blackhole. Would that be such a conflict you are refering to?

Comment: There's an entry that says "blackhole"? Your public subnets be routing `0.0.0.0/0` to the Internet gateway, and your private subnets should be routing `0.0.0.0/0` to the NAT Gateway.